# Copying non-adjacent words & joining them together

Tags: autohotkey

As the title already says, I would like to copy and join any number of (mostly) non-adjacent words in any app (Web browser, E-Mail, MS Word, Editor, Evernote etc.). That is, any words that I (mouse-)select and copy hitting the `5`-key while I simultaneously hold down the `F4` key *(but actually any hotkeys and modifiers that don't interfere with their normal functioning and which are also both easily and simultaneously reachable with the left hand would do)*.

This is what I came up with with my limited AHK-skills. The clipboard-part works, but for all I know not the `global`-variable (and therefore not the word-joining) nor the `F4 Down & 5`-hotkey-combo (without `Down` or without `& 5` it technically would, though):

```
global MyString := ""                    ; make string global to keep contents between {5}-key presses

~F4 Down & 5::                           ; copy any (non-adjacent) words with {5}-key as long as I hold down {F4}-key
    clipboard := ""
    Sleep 100
    Send ^c
    ClipWait, 1
    MyString := MyString Trim(clipboard) ; append lastly copied word to any words copied before (while holding down {F4})

~F4 Up::
    MsgBox, %MyString%                   ; show final string consisting of ALL copied words separated by a space
    MyString := ""                       ; reset string

Return
```

Ultimately, I would like to copy `%MyString%` to the clipboard as one single long string rather than show it in a message box. I think I'm already near to the solution.

Can you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never ending the first hotkey's execution block, so its execution bleeds into the hotkey below and your `MyString` gets reset every time.
Also if you have an `down`/`up` hotkey pair, you don't specify the first `down`, only the `up`.
Also, there's no need to make your variable [super-global](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Functions.htm#SuperGlobal).

Fixed script:

```
~F4 & 5::                         
    Clipboard := ""
    Sleep, 100
    Send, ^c
    ClipWait, 1
    MyString := MyString " " Trim(Clipboard) 
return

~F4 Up::
    MsgBox, % MyString                
    MyString := ""  
return
```

Pretty cool idea for a script btw. I might use something like this myself.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the flowers. The tests I had done in the meantime confirm that you are absolutely right, so answer accepted. If you liked my question then maybe you might consider upvoting it :-) Happy using our script"